# Expectation of twostep random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X:\Omega \to [0, 1]$ be a random variable and its density function be a uniform density. For each $x \in [0, 1]$, $Y_x:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable and its density function is $N(x^2, 1)$ which is normal distribution with mean $x^2$ and standard deviation 1. Let $Y$ be its value.

We first sample from $\Omega$ and its value is $X$, then we sample from $\Omega_X$ and its value is $Y$.

I want to know the expectation of $Y$.

Can I calculate the expectation of $Y_x$ first and then $E(Y)=E(X^2)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $EY=E(E(Y_X|X))=EX^{2}$.

Comment: Is it based on Fubini's theorem?

Comment: No, Fubini's Theorem is for product measures and it requires independence of random variables. Here it is given that $y$ has $N(x^{2},1)$ distribution when conditioned on $X$. This gives $E(Y|X)=X^{2}$.

Comment: $Y_x$ should be replaced with $Y_X$.